# Android 2.3.5 Gingerbread: Sort and do a cloud backup of photos

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, backup, photos, samsung-galaxy-y, cloud

I have a Samsung Galaxy Y and I want to sort camera pictures and do a cloud backup. Is it possible using the standard Gallery app and any other of it's factory resources?

I know Google Photos would do this in very simple and stylish way, but there is no version for Gingerbread devices (AFAIK, there is no way to upgrade this phone beyond 2.3.6).

Comment: You can backup using Google Drive if that's available in your phone. And Why do you want to sort the photos and in what criteria(Name,Size etc) you want to sort those photos?

Comment: I want to sort them by date and to separate them into private collections. I haven't really fooled around much on the Galaxy Y, but my other phone is in maintenance (parts will take months to arrive) and I must do some work on this one.

Comment: Well, As I already pointed you can use your preinstaled Google drive or Goolge Plus app for backing up your photos. Or you can use other cloud photo backup apps like [G Cloud Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.genie9.gcloudbackup), [CM Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ijinshan.kbackup) or [Dropbox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dropbox.android) etc. Also look for [other cloud photo backup apps](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=photo%20cloud%20backup&c=apps) in google play store. Later you can do the sorting after backup.

Comment: It actually didn't come with Plus nor Drive (customizing by my local phone operator, I think), but I will give it a try, thanks.

Make this an aswer and I will upvote it.

Comment: I really wish StackOverflow had a "follow person" feature like Quora does. Where can I suggest that?

Comment: Lucas Soares You can use @Username to mention me in your comments to notify me. If you want a new feature in the SE site then you can make a request in our meta site http://meta.stackexchange.com. ;)

Comment: But please use our search functionality or google to find out the question you are going to ask has already been asked by someone else. In your case the question has already been asked by someone else. Please look at [Is there a way to follow a user on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57334/is-there-a-way-to-follow-a-user-on-stack-overflow)

Comment: @Lucky I was trying different searches on meta right now, but your comment arrived faster than the searches. For this photo backup question I looked it up, and there were no answers useful on a Galaxy Y.

Comment: Great. Now I got notified about your last reply since you mentioned my name prefixed with @. ;) Please have a look at this answer to know about the difference on meta and main site. You need to search for the Galaxy Y issues on the main site(http://android.stackexchange.com). But since you were searching that on the meta site you din't get any relevant results. The meta site for Android Enthusiasts is http://meta.android.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from my commnets,

> Well, As I already pointed you can use your preinstaled [Google Drive](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.docs)
>   or [Goolge Plus](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.plus) app for backing up your photos. Or you can use other
>   cloud photo backup apps from the Play Store like [G Cloud Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.genie9.gcloudbackup), [CM Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ijinshan.kbackup) or [Dropbox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dropbox.android) etc.
>   Also look for [other cloud photo backup apps](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=photo%20cloud%20backup&c=apps) in google play store.
>   Later you can do the sorting after backup.

Once you have stored your photos backed up in the cloud storage, the uploaded images will also have properties stored with them for each image file. So once you restore it to your phone or download it to your computer you can sort the photos based on the `Date and Time` filter from the file property.